# Shopping cart price rules calculated using RRP/price

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules

It seems **shopping cart prices are always applied to the price in the cart**.

Is there a feature/module that allows shopping cart prices rules to be applied to the items original RRP/price regardless if it has a special price and or group price?

Answer (score 0):

Use this event observer to set the shopping cart rule to base price of items instead speical or any group price.

sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after

```
public function updateccollects(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
{

    $quote = $observer->getQuoteAddress();
    if ($quote->getData('address_type') == 'shipping')
    {
        // getting the items in cart
        $quoteObj=   $quote->getQuote();
        $cartItems  = $quoteObj->getAllVisibleItems(); 
        // print_r($cartItems);
        $totalPrice  = 0;
        foreach($cartItems as $item)
        {
            $proId= $item->getId();
            $productObj = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($proId);
            $originalPrice =   $productObj->getPrice();
            $totalBasePrice = $totalPrice + $originalPrice;
        }
        // get the applied rule ids
        $cartRuleId = $quoteObj->getAppliedRuleIds();
        $salesRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($cartRuleId);
        $applyRule       = $salesRule->getData('simple_action'); 
        $discountAmmount =   $salesRule->getData('discount_amount');
        if($applyRule == "by_percent")
        {

            $finalDiscountAmount =  $totalBasePrice*($discountAmmount/100);
        }
        $quote->setDiscountAmount($finalDiscountAmount);
    }

}
```